# Parse date from json in Django

Tags: python, json, django, date, datetime-parsing

I try to parse date field inside JSON object:

```
{
    "year": 1,
    "name": "marko",
    "date": "2015-10-1 3:00 PM GMT+1:00"
}
```

I try to something like:

```
db_object.date = datetime.datetime.strptime(dictionary.get('date'), '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M ')
```

but I get error...

I know that %d should be a zero based like:

```
01
```

but I get 1 in JSON.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using dateutil

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
parse("2015-10-1 3:00 PM GMT+1:00")
```